# Two column join between tables, one column with equal to and other columns with not equal to

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, equals

Two tables each with `6.4 million` records in SQL Server 2012. Let's say A and B. I have to join two tables based on two columns. Lets say `A.C1 = B.C1` and also `A.C2 <> B.C2.` Both `C1 and C2` are `nvarchar` columns. 
Table B does not have clustered index. I have the query as show below:

```
select B.C1...A.C12, A.C2...A.C5
from A
inner join B on A.C1 = B.C1
where A.C2 <> B.C2
```

This is taking over 16 min and up to 30 min. It does a full table scan on B as other columns from B. When it takes more than 30 mins, the query timeouts. Can you please let me know what is the best way to write this query.

Comment: Using indexes is a very important mostly if you have a bunch of data in your database.

Comment: In order to avoid a full table scan, you'd need an index on at least B.C1 (though B.C1 and B.C2 together would be optimal for this particular query). It doesn't _need_ to be clustered if you don't want it to be, but there needs to be some sort of index to avoid the full scan. There may be other ways to improve the performance as well but it depends on what the data actually is (e.g. if each C1/C2 combination is unique - and will always be unique - you could specify a unique index).

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a clustered index on table B, this would be a good opportunity to do so. C1 as the 1st key and C2 as the 2nd. You'll also want a similar (C1, C2), nonclustered index on A. Depending on columns in A, you may or may not want it to be a covering index...

In terms of readability, I'd format the code as so...

```
SELECT
    b.C1,
    ...
    b.C12,
    a.C2,
    ...
    a.C5
FROM
    A a
    JOIN B b
        ON a.C1 = b.C1
        AND a.C2 <> b.C2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select B.C1...A.C12, A.C2...A.C5
from A
inner join B on A.C1 = B.C1
```

minus

```
select B.C1...A.C12, A.C2...A.C5
from A
inner join B on A.C2 = B.C2
```

Comment: Lux, how would this improve the query performance, I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't have a question about your query:
In order to obtain a better performance on each of every query's:

1. Database Normalization including `Blob` Datatype.
2. Database has always an `indexes`.
3. Make sure you have a `High Speed` Machine Specs.
4. Database `Software` Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexed views. They improve query perfomance.

```
   --Set the options to support indexed views.  
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;  
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,  
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;  
GO  
--Create view with schemabinding.  
IF OBJECT_ID ('A.B', 'view') IS NOT NULL  
DROP VIEW A.B;  
GO  
CREATE VIEW A.B 
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
    SELECT  B.C1...A.C12, A.C2...A.C5
    FROM A 
    inner join B on A.C1 = B.C1 
    Where A.C2 <> B.C2;  
GO  
--Create an index on the view.  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1   
    ON A.B (B.C1, A.C12);  
GO
```

For further reference check this [create indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views)

Comment: Thank you very much Leo, I think this is one of the good option to use. What are the disadvantages of using it?

Comment: it has some handles when you want to do Group by, there is a way you have to do it.  Also check the link i gave, the section for "Additional requirements"